# Is this the correct way to update state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My Component looks like this:

```
import cloneDeep from "clone-deep";
import { Context } from "../../context";

const Component = () => {
  const context = useContext(Context);
  const [state, setState] = useState(
    { 
      _id: "123", 
      users: [
        { 
          _id: "1",
          points: 5
        },
        {
          _id: "2",
          points: 8 
        }
      ]
    }
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    context.socket.emit("points");

    context.socket.on("points", (socketData) => {

          setState(prevState => {
    const newState = {...prevState};
    const index = newState.users
      .findIndex(user => user._id == socketData.content._id);
    newState.users[index].points = socketData.content.points;
    return newState;
  })
      
    });

    return () => context.socket.off("points");
  }, []);



  return <div>(There is table with identificators and points)</div>
};
```

I wonder if this is the right approach. I just want to write the code in the right way.
Or maybe it's better with the use of deep cloning? Does it matter?

```
setState(prevState => {
const newState = cloneDeep(prevState);
const index = newState.users
  .findIndex(user => user._id == "2");
newState.users[index].points++;
return newState;
```

})

EDIT: I added the rest of the code to make it easier to understand.

Comment: This component does not return anything. Also it will end up in an infinite update loop as you are calling `setState` during render unconditionally which will trigger a new render again and again. Also you are mutating the object at `users[index]` which is not ideal and might result in breaking updates of components further down that rely on object identity to bail out from rendering.

Comment: It will create an infinite update loop as @trixn mentioned. You probably want to update the state in an event hadler i.e. onClick of any button etc, or an `useEffect` hook. Also, don't mutate the original state; to avoid that you can use `.map` on users.

Comment: Looks like this is a simplified version of the actual code, as this will not render, and will cause infinite loop. @nelkor, can you share the full code?
I'm guessing that your question, is about state management, and not rendering

Comment: @DaniilLoban I don't think that this kind of edit for changing code formatting from one perfectly readable style to another is beneficial. Also the `...` is based on assumptions that OP did not provide. If you want to know if there is any more code than presented please ask OP for clarification instead of editing.

Comment: Updating deeply nested state (especially containing arrays) can be hard. If you need to independently modify the array it is most likely easier to have separate states for the `users` and the other data so you can update them independently. You might also consider to use `useReducer` if you have a more complicated nested structure to update. Deep cloning the whole state object on any update is unnecessary and might lead to decreased performance depending on the use case.

Comment: @gilamran, I shared rest of code

Answer (score 1):

In your current code:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    setState((prevState) => {
      const newState = { ...prevState };
      const index = newState.users.findIndex((user) => user._id == "2");
      newState.users[index].points++;
      console.log({ prevState, newState });
      return newState;
    });
  }, []);
```

You can see that `prevState` is being mutated (points is 9):

```
    { 
      _id: "123", 
      users: [
        { 
          _id: "1",
          points: 5
        },
        {
          _id: "2",
          points: 9 // Mutated!
        }
      ]
    }
```

To avoid mutating the state, you have to use [not mutating methods](https://doesitmutate.xyz/) such as spread operator or map function:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    setState((prevState) => {
      const newState = ({
        ...prevState,
        users: prevState.users.map((user) =>
          user._id === "2"
            ? {
                ...user,
                points: user.points + 1
              }
            : user
        )
      })
      console.log({ prevState, newState });
      return newState
      }
    );
  }, []);
```

Now you can see that the prevState is not mutated:

```
    { 
      _id: "123", 
      users: [
        { 
          _id: "1",
          points: 5
        },
        {
          _id: "2",
          points: 8 // Not mutated :)
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Does it matter if it's mutated? React will still see that the state has changed (oldState !== newState) and re-render. The mutation shouldn't affect anything else?

Comment: Mutating and side-effects are generally not recomended in React. Could generate different kind of bugs so difficult to identify, since you are changing the state directly and not respecting the cycle of the component.

Comment: @FredStark It starts to matter when optimising performance, e.g. introducing `React.memo()`. Consider a refactoring where a list component is introduced that receives `users` as a prop. If you mutate the array instead of creating a new one it will bail out from rendering even if an element in the array has changed. Those kind of issues can be hard to find and debug and therefore it's best practice to also create new instances of parent objects when updating deeply nested data.

Comment: In both the question code and this answer, a new state object is created, so it will still re-render. I'm talking about the nested references, since they're shared between the old and new states. Props is a good example of where it could lead to funny behaviour, but I would assume that the same would apply there if it's state is changed. Are there some practical examples of when it would matter that nested properties have been mutated?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work, but the problem will start when your state becomes bigger.
You currently have only two properties on the state, the `_id` and the `users`. If in the future will add more and more properties like `loggedUser` and `settings` and `favorites`, and more... your application will render everything on every state change.

At this point you will have to start thinking about other solutions to state management, like redux, mobx, or just split the state to smaller `useState`, also you can look into `useReducer` in complex structures.